# How to pull out the ARGB component from BitmapContext on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, image, colors, bitmap, rgb

I'm trying to get ARGB components from CGBitmapContext with the following codes:

```
-(id) initWithImage: (UIImage*) image   //create BitmapContext with UIImage and use 'pixelData' as the pointer
{

        CGContextRef    context = NULL;
        CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace;
        int             bitmapByteCount;
        int             bitmapBytesPerRow;

        bitmapBytesPerRow   = (image.size.width * 4);                       
        bitmapByteCount     = (bitmapBytesPerRow * image.size.height);

        colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();                         
        pixelData = malloc( bitmapByteCount );      //unsigned char* pixelData is defined in head file
        context = CGBitmapContextCreate (pixelData,                         
                        image.size.width,
                        image.size.height,
                        8,    // bits per component
                        bitmapBytesPerRow,
                        colorSpace,
                        kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst
                        );
        CGColorSpaceRelease( colorSpace );                                  

        CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height), image.CGImage);
        pixelData = CGBitmapContextGetData(context);
        return self;
}
```

```
-(float) alphaAtX:(int)x y:(int)y   //get alpha component using the pointer 'pixelData' 
{
    return pixelData[(y *width + x) *4 + 3];    //+0 for red, +1 for green, +2 for blue, +3 for alpha
}
```

-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"MacDrive.png"];    //load image

```
[self initWithImage:img];   //create BitmapContext with UIImage
float alpha = [self alphaAtX:20 y:20];  //store alpha component
```

}

When I try to store red/green/blue, they turn out to be always 240. And alpha is always 255.

So I think maybe something is wrong with the pointer. It could not return the correct ARGB data I want. Any ideas about what's wrong with the code?

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to do something very similar to what I was doing when I asked [This Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448125/how-to-get-pixel-data-from-a-uiimage-cocoa-touch-or-cgimage-core-graphics). The marked-best answer served me very well. Hope it will do you, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you're leaking memory, the pixelData memory never gets freed.

For your usage, it's better to let the CGContext calls manage the memory. Simply pass NULL i.s.o. pixelData, and as long as you keep the reference count up on your context, the `CGBitmapContextGetData(context)` will remain valid.

You're using alpha as if it was the last entry (RGBA, not ARGB), use it as such in the creation of your context, or adapt the `alphaAtX` code. I'm not sure if you want premultiplied, if it's just to check alpha values, you don't.

All in all something like:

```
[...]
CGContextRelease(context);
context = CGBitmapContextCreate (NULL,                                                     
                                    image.size.width,
                                    image.size.height,
                                    8,    // bits per component
                                    bitmapBytesPerRow,
                                    colorSpace,
                                    kCGImageAlphaLast
                                    );
CGColorSpaceRelease( colorSpace );                                                                      

CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height), image.CGImage);
pixelData = CGBitmapContextGetData(context);
[...]
```

with context being a member variable, initialized to NULL, will already be a step in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would check to see if the context returned from your `CGBitmapContextCreate` call is valid (that is, make sure `context != NULL`). I'd also check to make sure your originally loaded image is valid (so, make sure `img != nil`).

If your context is nil, it may be because your image size is unreasonable, or else your pixel data format is unavailable. Try using `kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast` instead?

Second, you don't need to use `CGBitmapContextGetData` - you can just use the `pixelData` pointer you passed in in the first place. You should also `CGContextRelease` your context before leaving your `initWithImage:` function to avoid a leak.

I also note that you're using `kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst`. This means that the alpha component is *first*, not last, in your image, so you want an offset of 0 for the alpha component in your `alphaAtX:y:` function.

Does any of that help?